# How can I avoid error trying to get the developer license?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

When clicking on 'get developer license' from the admin interface  I get the following error. How can I fix it?

```
500 Internal Server Error
XDMP-CAST: (err:FORG0001) xs:integer(fn:substring-before($version, ".")) -- Invalid cast: "" cast as xs:integer
in /3.X/default.xqy, at 192:0 [0.9-ml]
$version = ""
$hostname = ""
$cpus = ""
$platform = ""
$target = ""
$licensee = ""
$company = ""
$email = ""
$website = ""
$phonenumber = ""
$usage = ""
$title = ""
$employees = ()
$address = ""
$city = ""
$state = ""
$zip = ""
$retrying = ()
$host = "developer.marklogic.com"
$mint = "mint.marklogic.com"
$mint-url = "http://mint.marklogic.com/3X/demo-keygen-3.X.xqy"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe your issue in more detail, please? E.g. by adding code, commands or screen shots which describe your problem. Please have also a look to the Help Center, especially for [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Comment: I get the same error message using MarkLogic 9.0-6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding your marklogic version (9.0-6 in my case) to the url like this:

```
https://developer.marklogic.com/license/3.X/default.xqy?version=9.0-6&hostname=&cpus=&platform=&target=&licensee=&company=&email=&website=&phonenumber=&address=&city=&state=&zip=&title=&usage=
```

This gets me to the next window where you can request your licence key. I am still waiting for a email with my licence key though.

**Update:** This issue has been resolved by MarkLogic. My suggested solution to request a licence key should not be needed anymore. See comments on this answer for details.

Comment: Curious, if you execute `xdmp:version()` in QConsole, does it return `9.0-6` or an empty sequence?

Comment: I do get `9.0-6`. Still waiting for my licence key email thought.

Comment: Strange, because that license page submits the form to `http://developer.marklogic.com/license/default.xqy` and has hidden input elements and the value of version uses that function: `<input type="hidden" name="version" value="{xdmp:version()}"/>`

Comment: There seems to be a url redirect. The initial request contains all form data (version, hostname and so on). But the redirected request does not seem to have that data.

Comment: First request is a POST to `http://developer.marklogic.com/license/default.xqy `(contains version data and so on). This Request returns 301, next request is a GET to `**https**://developer.marklogic.com/license/default.xqy`. This one does not contain the form data. So i guess there is a misconfiguration of your http server while redirecting from http to https ?

Comment: The issue with the redirect has been resolved. It should now redirect to HTTPS *with the querystring parameters* and "just work" without intervention.